# logistic regression vs poisson rate regression

Tags: logistic, modeling, poisson-regression

I have some confusion about logistic regression, Poisson regression and Poisson rate regression and I hoping to get some answers that can clear the cobwebs in my mind regarding this confusion.

My outcome is a binary "Yes-Smoke", "No-Smoke" variable.
`No-Smoke : 3154 (86%), Yes-Smoke : 493(14%)`

One row per subject, no repeat observation.

In addition there are `time variables`. Specifically ,

```
   Season:{Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall} & 
   Year: { 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020}
```

This is the distribution of Yes and No each Season, each year.

```
    Time         Yes,Smoke(%)  No,Smoke(%)
    2017:Winter  92.7          7.3
    2017:Spring  91.6          8.44
    2017:Summer  92.5          7.49
    2017:Fall    93.8          6.2

    2018:Winter  93.5          6.5
    2018:Spring  93.7          6.3
    2018:Summer  92.6          7.4
    2018:Fall    94.8          5.15

    2019:Winter  92.4          5.61
    2019:Spring  93.7          6.32
    2019:Summer  95.5          4.5
    2019:Fall    93.4          6.58

    2020:Winter  94.4          5.6
    2020:Spring  93.1          6.9
    2020:Summer  93.4          6.6
    2020:Fall    91.3          8.7
```

I am wondering if I should apply logistic regression for this scenario or rate Poisson regression since I also have number of yes and no for each season , each year? Any advise is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the raw counts from which the `Yes,Smoke(%)` and `No,Smoke(%)` values are calculated?

Comment: @Dave, Hi Dave, yes I do.

Comment: Are there (possibly) multiple responses from the same respondent across years? If so, do you or do you not track the participant ID across multiple years?

Comment: @AdamO, good question. Answer is no. Each respondent only one observation at one point in time (season +year). Not tracking respondent over time.

Comment: @SundownBrownbear you're saying, for instance, you have n=500 who each contributed 4 responses over 4 years for a total of 2000 observations in a complete balanced design correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in `smoke` vs `no-smoke`, you probably want to model your binary response variable using logistic regression. This will give you the **average probability** of someone being a smoker (or not) given your predictor variable(s).

If you have further information on the number of cigarettes smoked, you could model the **average count** of cigarettes smoked given your predictor variable(s) using a Poisson or negative binomial regression model.

If you further have information on how many cigarettes smoked per day (week, month, etc), you could model the **average rate** of cigarettes smoked given your predictor variable(s), also using a Poisson or negative binomial regression model.

Eventually everything depends on your scientific model first, then you can derive a statistical model to test that scientific model.

**EDIT:** I immediately associated `smoke` with being a smoker, that might have been wrong. However, the general idea should apply to any other binary variable as well.

Comment: thank you., I will explore these options.